# Split IPython Magic Shell Multiple Lines

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to run a very long shell command in IPython using the `!` operator. How do I split the command onto multiple lines?

For instance,

```
 !awk -v c=0 '{{if (a[$$1]) print $$0 a[$$1]; else if (b[$$2]) print $$0 b[$$2] else {{print $$0 " common_" c; a[$$1] = b[$$2] = " common_" c; c++}}}}' foo.txt | column -t
```

A command like this quickly becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\`, press enter, continue typing, use another `\` and enter until you are done.

E.g.

```
In [1]: !ls \
   ...: *.txt
aws-forum.txt  encyclic.txt

In [2]:
```

Comment: The same can be used for other magic commands, e.g. `%run -i ...`.

Comment: Will this work if the Notebook is being ran on a Windows System?

Comment: @FilBot3 I have no idea as I run Linux only. But I would expect it to work there too as it runs within IPython shell.

Comment: Tried it out, and it does work in Jupyter Lab on a Windows system. Even if the notebook was launched from PowerShell. I tried using Subprocess, but it shells out to cmd.exe instead of the shell that launched it like PowerShell.